# android change list item in listview with custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, colors, adapter

i would like to change the background color from my listview.
the background from the number should change by the status

```
1 = red
2 = grey
3 = green
4 = yellow
```

thats the code from my custom adapter(don't work):

```
TextView number = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);

switch(Integer.parseInt(status[position])){
case 1: number.setBackgroundColor(0xff0000);
        break;

case 2: number.setBackgroundColor(0xdfdfdf);
        break;

case 3: number.setBackgroundColor(0x00ff00);
        break;

case 4: number.setBackgroundColor(0xffff00);
        break;

default :
        break;
}
```

why it doesn't work?

Comment: what is status[]? You can directly pass position to switch case.

Comment: status[position] = 1,2,3 or 4 to change the background color

Comment: You want to change listview background or list item background?

Comment: @rapha31: Maybe you're missing the alpha channel information since Android takes the format #ARGB, for example #AARRGGBB, where **A** is the alpha channel, and **RGB** is Red Green Blue. So, in your case, if you want transparent alpha channel, then you would have `0x00ff0000` for **case 1**, or for opaque channel, you would have `0xffff0000`

Comment: in the list item ist a textview, i want to change the background of this textview(tv_number)

Comment: @ChuongPham you have absolutely right. that is the solution. many thanks

Comment: @rapha31: I have posted my answer based on my comment above. If the answer is correct, please tick it so others who'll read your post in the future will know that my answer is the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're setting background for a widget, you'll also need to add the alpha channel to the colour you wished to use since Android requires the colour to be in the format **#ARGB**, for example `#AARRGGBB`, where **A** is the alpha channel, and **RGB** is Red Green Blue.

So, in your case, if you want transparent (**00** prefix) alpha channel, then you need to do this for **case 1**:

```
number.setBackgroundColor(0x00ff0000);
```

Or, for opaque channel (**ff** prefix), do this:

```
number.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int cc[] = {R.color.red,r.color.blue}
```

set the background of the textview in the getview method as

```
number.setBackgroundColor(cc[position]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ; replace your code with this.

```
TextView number = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);

    switch(Integer.parseInt(status[position])){
    case 1: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            break;

    case 2: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            break;

    case 3: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;

    case 4: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            break;

    default :
            break;
    }
```

Comment: @rapha31 but here you ask for setbackgroundcolor  not like alpha , OK

Answer (score 1):

Did you get status[position] value correct?
You can write a Log statemet to check the value or debug the code.

If your values are coming correct then try below code snippet.

```
TextView number = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);

switch(Integer.parseInt(status[position])){
case 1: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        break;

case 2: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4D4D4D"));
        break;

case 3: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
        break;

case 4: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
        break;

default :
        break;
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

What does your status function return and what is rowView? Bit hard to say without saying more.

A few other suggestions:

You should avoid hard coding values like this, it is good practice to use a colors.xml file in your re/values/ folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary_white">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Then reference your resource the same way you would a string but R.color.primary_white

Also magic numbers like this are bad practice. Try settings some static values at the top of your file:

```
static int STATUS_RED = 1;
```

....

```
case STATUS_RED:
```

Here is a tutorial on changing background and styling a row in a listview:

http://webdeveloperpadawan.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/android-listview-with-differing-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
TextView number = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);

switch(position+1){
case 1: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        break;

case 2: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        break;

case 3: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        break;

case 4: number.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        break;

default :
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code in getView Method..

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

        switch (position % 4) {
                case 0:
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
    }
```

Hope It Helps...